# How do I query_posts in cat=1 AND not in cat=2

Tags: categories, query-posts

Let's say I have 3 categories, College (cat=1), Corporate (cat=2), and Idea of the Week (cat=3)

There is a home page for College and a home page for Corporate.

On the College home page, in one section I want to show recent post that is in College but not not in Idea of the Week.

My initial attempt:

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=1&cat=-3' ); the_post(); ?>'
```

but this appears to pull post found in EITHER cat 1 OR cat 3.

Same home page, in a second section I want to show recent post that is in College AND in Idea of the Week.

I'm using:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(1,3), 'posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=DESC' )); the_post(); ?>
```

This seems to work as needed. Is there a similar 'category_*and*_not' function that I can use for the first query?

Answer (score 3):

First, [never use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts), use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for additional queries, or [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query.

Refer to [`WP_Query` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for a complete list of available arguments. You want to use `category__not_in` in this case:

```
$args = array(
    'category__in' => array(1),
    'category__not_in' => array(2)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```